# Cumulative Hierarchy of ZFA set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm studying set theory using the book *Set Theory - The Third Millennium Edition* by Thomas Jech. In chapter 6, he defines the cumulative hierarchy by ordinal induction as follows:

- $V_0=\emptyset$,
- $V_{\alpha+1}=P(V_{\alpha})$,
- $V_{\alpha}=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}V_\beta$, if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal.

In chapter 15, more precisely on page 249, he defines a cumulative hierarchy for ZFA set theory as follows:

- $P^0(A)=A$,
- $P^{\alpha+1}(A)=P^{\alpha}(A)\cup P(P^{\alpha}(A))$,
- $P^{\alpha}(A)=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}P^{\beta}(A)$, if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal.

My question might be a little silly but why did he define $P^{\alpha+1}(A)=P^{\alpha}(A)\cup P(P^{\alpha}(A))$ instead of just $P^{\alpha+1}(A)=P(P^{\alpha}(A))$? I mean $P^{\alpha}(A)\subset P(P^{\alpha}(A))$, right!? So $P^{\alpha}(A)\cup P(P^{\alpha}(A)) = P(P^{\alpha}(A))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the elements of $A$ are **atoms** - they have no elements, and so aren't subsets of anything. Consequently we already have $$A\cap P(A)=\emptyset,$$ or put another way $$P^0(A)\not\subseteq P^1(A).$$ When there happen to not be any atoms (or if you prefer, $A=\emptyset$) things are surprisingly nice, but the default is that we do indeed need to explicitly include each level of the desired hierarchy in the next.

Comment: Ohh I understand now, thank you very much.